# Better way for repetitive copying results into larger output array

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, python-xarray

Here is the setup of the problem. The output dataset is called "climoData" with two DataArrays (mean, stddev). They are a function of latitude, longitude, level, lead time (a number based on a forecast), and dayofyear. The output is a "climatology" of a lot of different forecast files. The DataArrays are all initialized to NaN:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:    (latitude: 121, longitude: 240, level: 9, lead: 47,
                dayofyear: 366)
Coordinates:
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 -90.0 -88.5 -87.0 -85.5 ... 87.0 88.5 90.0
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 0.0 1.5 3.0 4.5 ... 354.0 355.5 357.0 358.5
  * level      (level) float64 925.0 850.0 700.0 500.0 ... 200.0 100.0 50.0 10.0
  * lead       (lead) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ... 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46
  * dayofyear  (dayofyear) int64 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 ... 360 361 362 363 364 365 366
Data variables:
    mean     (dayofyear, lead, level, latitude, longitude) float32 nan ... nan
    stddev   (dayofyear, lead, level, latitude, longitude) float32 nan ... nan
```

I then read in a set of forecast files and take an average (and standard deviation) across different dimensions in that dataset. One of the resulting DataArray (let's call it "forecastAvg" for the mean) looks like this:

```
<xarray.DataArray 'u' (dayofyear: 47, level: 9, latitude: 121, longitude: 240)>
dask.array<stack, shape=(47, 9, 121, 240), dtype=float32, chunksize=(1, 9, 121, 240), chunktype=numpy.ndarray>
Coordinates:
  * longitude  (longitude) float32 0.0 1.5 3.0 4.5 ... 354.0 355.5 357.0 358.5
  * latitude   (latitude) float32 -90.0 -88.5 -87.0 -85.5 ... 87.0 88.5 90.0
  * level      (level) int32 925 850 700 500 300 200 100 50 10
  * dayofyear  (dayofyear) int64 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ... 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48
```

Here, the dayofyear values in forecastAvg also correspond to "lead". So, for example, the value corresponding to dayofyear=2 in forecastAvg (forecastAvg[0,:,:,:]) is Lead 0, For dayofyear=3 in forecastAvg, that is Lead 1, etc. Hence, for Lead 0, the value of forecastAvg[0,:,:,:] should go in climoData['mean'][1,0,:,:,:], forecastAvg[1,:,:,:] should go into climoData['mean'][2,1,:,:,:], etc. These pairings can change with other forecast files (e.g., in another set of files, dayofyear=3 will be Lead 0).

This is how I was doing the reassignment/copying. The code absolutely works, but it takes far too long (~40-60 seconds per time in just this loop, which when processing hundred of files is just too long):

```
doy = forecastAvg.dayofyear.values
for n,d in enumerate(doy): 
    climoData['mean'][d-1,n,:] = forecastAvg[n,:]
    climoData['stddev'][d-1,n,:] = forecastStdDev[n,:]
```

Anyway to speed this up? I feel like there should be a way, but I am drawing a blank. Thanks!

Comment: `climoData` has dimensions `lead` and `dayofyear`. But is there really a value for each lead-dayofyear-combination, or is there always just one dayofyear value for a given lead that is not NaN?